# Linux write basic commands and make it executable using single line of code

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, scripting

Hello is this possible to create a file with these line of codes below and make it as an executable file on single line of code? Currently I'm doing manually. Your response is highly appreciated. Thank you

**Manual Steps**

-vi + content

-chmod +x filename

**This is the file content:**

#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt install curl -y

sudo apt install -y default-jdk

Screenshot:

[CLI Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4Gnj.png)

Objective to write everything using one line of code

Comment: It is kind of unclear what you want. Cant you put all in a single script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is crucial that it be a one-liner and vi is not a requirement:

`echo -e '#!/bin/bash\nsudo apt-get update\nsudo apt install curl -y\nsudo apt install -y default-jdk' > test.sh && chmod +x test.sh && ./test.sh`

If vi is a requirement you could do something like:

`vim file.txt "+i#!/bin/bash" "+osudo apt-get update" "+o..." and so on`

in place of the echo, but this seems much less effective to me and I'm less familiar with using vi in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a `test.sh` with bash script (we can call it `download.sh`):

```bash
# 1. write script content to test.sh
cat <<EOT >> test.sh
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt install curl -y

sudo apt install -y default-jdk
EOT

# 2. make it executable
chmod +x test.sh
```

When you execute `bash download.sh`, it will generate a `test.sh` automatically.